# Rails collection on form wanting extra (Tenant ID) field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

I have a dilemma...I have put together a multi-tenant app and I'm having an issue with one form and action. The form (Profile) has a collection select where one selects the skills applicable. There is a many-to-many with Profile <- Taggings -> Tags. The Tag records appear in the collection for select, with multi-select enabled.

When you select some skills and save the profile record, in the profile update action, Rails throws:

**Validation failed: Tenant must exist**

This seems to be coming from the Taggings table, as when I remove the relationship with Tenant, no error and the profile record saves successfully. If I create a tagging record directly from Rails console, the tenant_id populates and the record saves.

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params) < fails here
        format.html { redirect_to profiles_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
```

Params (if I must insert tenant_id here, I expect within the tag id array, but how?):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"longobscurestring",
 "profile"=>
  {"description"=>"",
   "tag_ids"=>
    ["",
     "b39b38eb-a90b-434b-9457-1f3b67cee54e",
     "08d90ee7-3194-4fec-acee-bcecfae1e8e7",
     "ee8de96d-1206-4d73-bcf0-0b99f995569a",
     "469ce954-b2bd-49d5-9dbc-0636b4da43c8",
     "38b90691-d3f0-4c9d-8b5f-2c644a894d45",
     "77a332d9-feed-4f88-8133-19066b5d33bc",
     "05c145ce-a8ff-4105-a713-073da60184b5",
     "8d6f98e3-9c3e-4f45-8c7d-36b177b557af"],
   "contact_direct"=>"false"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"1728fcc4-f2e2-49de-9a39-5c67502b8a85"}
```

Profile form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @profile, url: profile_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :input_html => {:cols=>100, :rows=>5} %>

    <%= f.input :tag_ids, label: 'Skills', as: :select, collection: Tag.active.order(:name), label_method: :name, input_html: { multiple: true } %>
    <div>
      <span>People may contact me:</br></span>
      <div class="radio-inline margin-10" style="text-align:left">
        <%= f.input :contact_direct, label: '', as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['Directly', true], ['Through my manager', false]] %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="actions">
      <% if ( can? :manage, :all or current_user.id == @profile.user_id) %>
        <%= f.button :submit, 'Save', class: "btn btn-success" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "Back", profiles_path(:search => {:column => 'First', :direction => 'Up', :name => ''}), class: "btn btn-primary link-as-button" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Profile model associations:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tenant
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

Taggings model associations:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :competence, :integer, default: 0

  belongs_to :tenant
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :profile, optional: true
  has_one :user, through: :profile
  has_many :endorsements, inverse_of: 'tagging'
  has_many :endorsers, through: :endorsements
```

All tables have had RLS implemented through pg policies. Without tenant_id on the taggings record though, one can access the record through another tenant.

Please let me know anything else required here to debug. Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding into the Tagging model an after_initialize callback to the following:

```
  def set_tenant_id
    if new_record?
        self.tenant_id = self.tag.tenant_id
    end
  end
```

Feel free to say if this is bad practice...but I can't see any other way at present.